# How to stop range function at some point

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, range

I want to give the keys(in this case integer, starting from 1) to values exactly what amount of the input is. For example, if there are 2 users, i want the output to be: {1: {info}, 2: {info}}.

My question is if there is any way to make it work like that? I'm currently trying to use range() function(I gave 21 as a stop argument because max amount of user info that can be entered is 21). I've tried many things, but nothing worked. I'm stuck on this :/ If anyone could help me, would be much appreciated

```
emptyDict = []
scores = {}
age = {}

adLoop = True
while adLoop:
    user_input_name = input("Your name: ")
    user_input_age = int(input("Your age: "))
    user_input_score = int(float(input("Your score: ")))
    result = {"name": user_input_name, "age": user_input_age, "score": user_input_score}
    emptyDict.append(result)
    user_input_continue = input("Would you like to enter your info?: Y/N: ").lower()
    if user_input_continue == "y":
        adLoop = True
    elif user_input_continue == "n":
        adLoop = False
        print(emptyDict)
        if len(emptyDict) == 20:
            adLoop = False
            print(emptyDict)


for i in emptyDict:
    test = range(1, 21)
    for b in test:
        scores[b] = i

print(scores)
```

Comment: range ends just before the last value. change it to 22.

Comment: Ah, I know that, but that's not my question. I want it to stop in case there are 2 users. When I'm using 21, input is equaled to every integer from 1 to 21

Comment: why not use `enumerate`, I'm sort of confused what the nested for loop is doing. You are only ever going to get the last value from the `emptyDict`

Comment: I don't know why you need this key if you could keep it  in `emptyDict` and use `emptyDict[0]` instead of `score[1]` to get what you need.

Comment: if you really need it then `for b, i in enumerate(emptyDict, 1): scores[b] = i`. or shorter `scores.update(enumerate(emptyDict, 1))`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why can't you keep it in list `emptyDict` and use it.

---

Use `enumerate()` to get item and its number on list (+start_value in `enumerate(..., start_value)`)

```
for idx, item in enumerate(emptyDict, 1): 
    scores[idx] = item
```

or shorter

```
scores.update(enumerate(emptyDict, 1))
```

or without creating empty dict at start

```
score = dict(enumerate(emptyDict, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

your last loop is wrong. you should determine the length of "emptyDict" using range, then add a key,value pair in the loop to scores

```
for i in range(0,len(emptyDict)):                                                                                        
    scores[i] = emptyDict[i]
print(scores)
```

Comment: there are better methods then `range(len())`